# NFSv4 Server Bind Exports

Tags: server, mount, nfs

I have been trying to set up a NFSv4 Server with one export. In the exported directory, I want mounted file systems via bind and also data stored in the exported directory.

For example:

- /data

  - /bind_mount1
  - /bind_mount2
  - /bind_mount3
  - /dir1
  - /dir2
  - /dir3

The current exports config:

```
/data       *(rw,nohide,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,insecure_locks,async,insecure)
```

When I mount the export, I can access the directories and files fine but the bind mount are empty.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the `nohide` option to `crossmnt`, and then restart your NFS server.